# create react app not loading css background images in dev or build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, create-react-app

I'm having difficulty with some background images not loading.  I've made some significant modifications to the initial create react app, my folder structure is now as follows:

> Note: I have omitted some files & folders, if you need more please let me know.

```
App/
 node_modules/
 src/
  client/
   build/
   node_modules/
   public/
   src/
    css/
     App.css
    images/
     tree.png
     yeti.png
    App.jsx
  server/
 package.json
 Procfile
```

Here are the steps I take to create this issue:

```
$ cd src/server && npm run dev
```

This will boot up the dev server and open the browser to my app, everything is working fine except for some elements on the page not displaying a image.

> Note: I load in an image **yeti.png** and this renders fine.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/App.css';
import yeti from './images/yeti.png';

const Footer = function(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Yeti />
      <Trees />
    </div>
    );
};

const Yeti = function(props) {
  return (        
      <img
        src={yeti}
        className="yeti yeti--xs"
        alt="Yeti"
      />
    );
};

const Trees = function(props) {
  return (        
      <div className="trees">
        <div className="trees__tree trees__tree--1"></div>
        <div className="trees__tree trees__tree--2"></div>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Footer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.css**

```
.trees {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 110px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.trees__tree {
    background-size: 30px;
    background: url('../images/tree.png') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
}

.trees__tree--1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 6%;
}

.trees__tree--2 {
    margin: 2% 0 0 4%;
}
```

When I inspect the elements in Chrome, the path to the images appears to be correct.  When I hover over the path to the image in the styles tab of my inspector the image appears.

[image: styles source]

Note that the path for the image I import is similar to the path for the background image:

[image]

If I were to import the `tree.png` as `import tree from './images/tree.png';` and change my two `<div>` elements to `<img src={tree} role="presentation" className="trees__tree trees__tree--1" />` and `<img src={tree} role="presentation" className="trees__tree trees__tree--2" />` the images will of course load.

How can I get the background images to display?  I have other background images in the app that are not loading so the previously mentioned bandaid will not help me.  I'm afraid to eject my app and mess with the configuration.

I'm also having the same problem when I build the app.

If you need to see more of the source you can view it at https://github.com/studio174/ispellits but bare in mind I have simplied this example to isolate the problem.  The issue I am having is actually in the `Footer.jsx` and `Footer.css`

Comment: you can hover over the image src in the class inspector and see the image preview?

Comment: @4m1r Yes I can, I was unable to capture that with my screenshot, but chrome is displaying the image when I hover the path of both the imported image and the background image

Comment: Can you file an issue please? I'll try to remember to reply to this but it would be much better if you could just file an issue in Create React App repo so it's visible there, and I will see it next time I open the issue tracker.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue was purely an issue with CSS in the `App.css` file:

**App.css**

```
.trees__tree {    
    background: url('../images/tree.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px; /** moved this property down */
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Also, if it helps anyone else to know, the problem is that the blanket css "background" overwrites any background specific rules that have already been declared. by moving them down it redeclares the size after the background has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was specifically that I did not have `background-size: 30px;` defined. Thanks for this.

Answer (score -3):

Add homepage in package.json to run build in any apache server

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://{servername}/{foldername}/",

}
```

then  create build in react using

1. `npm run build`
2. `npm install -g serve`
3. `serve -s build`
4. Copy build folder and paste in server like xampp/htdocs and hit url