# REACT:JSX inline style: Unable to render image via backgroundImage style property

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, jsx

Unable to render image via the backgroundImage style property but able to render the image properly in the image src tag.

```
import BannerAnim from 'rc-banner-anim';
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.less';
import 'rc-banner-anim/assets/index.css';
import  './carousal.css';
import umberlla  from '../../images/umb.jpg';


const { Element } = BannerAnim;
const BgElement = Element.BgElement;
const umberllaImage = '../../images/umb.jpg';
const umberllaStyle = {
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + umberllaImage + ')',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundColor: '#364D79',
        backgroundBlendMode: 'luminosity',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
};

function Carousal() {
    return (
        <div>
      <BannerAnim type="across">
                      <BgElement
            id="bg"
            key="bg"
            className="bg"
            style={ umberllaStyle }
          />

        <BgElement
          key="bg"
          className="bg"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://os.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/uaQVvDrCwryVlbb.jpg)',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
          }}
        />

    </BannerAnim>

    <img src={umberlla} alt="text"></img>
    </div>

  );
}


export default Carousal;
```

I could see a similar post here but it is not helping.
[create react app not loading css background images in dev or build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918681/create-react-app-not-loading-css-background-images-in-dev-or-build)

**Both the styles are not working**

**Style1:**

```
 style={ umberllaStyle }
```

**Style2:**

```
 style={{backgroundImage: 'url(https://os.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/uaQVvDrCwryVlbb.jpg)'}}
```

**But this is working**

```
 <img src={umberlla} alt="text"></img>
```

Comment: have you checked if element is not collapsed to 0x0 size?

Comment: Thanks, @skyboxer yes the height for the bgElement was 0. Now I added height and width for bgElement. now the second style the direct cdn url is working.

Comment: for the first style, only the background color is visible not the image.

Comment: use this umberlla instead of umberllaImage

Comment: yes did the same worked. Thank you so much, struck with this last 2 days.

Comment: @skyboxer if you can put the same in the answer I can vote